# Python Selenium Can't find button on HTML

Tags: python, selenium

I'm fairly new to selenium.
I'm doing some tests with selenium for Python.
As a an exercise, I need to lo access a web delivery service, and get a short listing of stores.
However, I'm not able to get pass the first page.
This is the url:

https://web.cornershopapp.com/stores-search/tech

In this site, I need to "click" on the "Cancelar" button, then enter a postal code (like 52989), then click on "Continuar" and that's it... I can then scrape the store listing that appears.

However, right from the start I get all sort of error messages in the console

I'm doing something like this:

```
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', options=options)
    driver.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    cancel_button = soup.find("span", text="Cancelar")
    print(cancel_button)
```

But I can't find the cancel button, never mind clicking it, or entering a postal code in the next step. The resulting html doesn't seem to match the html I get when manually inspecting on Chrome.

Any suggestions on how to do this?
Or, is there maybe a way to manually do this preliminar actions by myself, and then let the script scrape the stores after getting the listing?

The errors I get are:

```
[23968:11884:0603/100416.187:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [10:04:16.188] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1054 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: Uno de los dispositivos conectados al sistema no funciona. (0x1F)
[23968:11884:0603/100416.189:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [10:04:16.189] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1054 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: Uno de los dispositivos conectados al sistema no funciona. (0x1F)
[23968:11884:0603/100416.189:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [10:04:16.189] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1054 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: Uno de los dispositivos conectados al sistema no funciona. (0x1F)
```

Comment: When I clicked on `Cancel` button, I see a drop down, I can not enter 52989 postal code there.

Comment: @cruisepandey That's strange. I just tried again using an Incognito window. Right after clicking the "Cancelar" button, I get another screen asking for a postal code and a "Continuar" button. No drop downs :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the below code :

```
executable_path = r"C:\\Users\\etc\\Desktop\\Selenium+Python\\chromedriver.exe"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path, options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("https://web.cornershopapp.com/stores-search/tech")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Cancel']/.."))).click()
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_tag_name('select'))
select.select_by_visible_text('México')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[placeholder='Zip code']"))).send_keys('52989')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Continue']/.."))).click()
```

Comment: Woah! This is perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the BeautifulSoup module so I would just use `driver.find_element_by_css_selector(thecssSelectorOfTheCancelButton).click()`
This will click this button, similarly, if you want to find the text of this element, you can change it to `driver.find_element_by_css_selector(thecssSelectorOfTheCancelButton).text`
If you just want to print the element for some reason, you can just do `print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector(thecssSelectorOfTheCancelButton))`.
I always recommend using css selectors as they are the most versatile selectors.